# Rewrite logic using kafka balanced consumer to instead use Kafka Connect Sink

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have some application logic, written in Python using pykafka, that is doing something like this:

```
    consumer = self.get_balanced_consumer()
    while True:
        msg = consumer.consume(block=False)
        if not msg:
            break
        self._work(msg)
        consumer.commit_offsets()
```

What is the equivalent logic using the Kafka Connect API?

Comment: Kafka Connect is a tool to sink data from a topic to a location (database, file system) or to source data from a data store to a topic.  Are you looking to take data from a topic and save it somewhere?

Comment: @franzke Yes, in this case the _work() method is writing the message into a custom database.

Comment: And your custom database is not here? https://www.confluent.io/hub/

Comment: @cricket_007 Affirmative. I think basically I need to implement my own connector, similar to what is in that list.

Comment: Well, that would be done using Java, not Python. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Is there some sort of generic Connector that will just give me JSON or something?

Comment: There is a datagen connector https://www.confluent.io/blog/easy-ways-generate-test-data-kafka